# CSS not loading on certain subdomains?

Tags: css, http

I've noticed that whenever I visit a subdomain (e.g. www.) of my website, the normal index loads but without any styling. Looking into the Inspector I found:

```
Origin http://www.songnova.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

How can I address this?

Comment: What is the path to your css file from the subdomains? It probably has to be the full path.

Comment: Do you mean I should link directly instead of relatively?

Comment: Exactly, please give it a try.

Comment: Tried it, same issue.

Comment: It appears that that the stylesheet being referenced does not take into account the "www." – it's the same URL for both versions. That's why I'm confused as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the css link to "http://songnova.com/css/main.css" and it worked.
Maybe the problem in the less library you're using